# django - javascript not working when in an included template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have a template in django called `base.html` that is calling another template through the `{% include 'gui/page.html' %}`

in that template I have the following javascript which allows the ability to select an an entire text field when setup like `<p>This text I will select all</p>`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('p').dblclick(function(e){

         $(this).selectText();
             e.preventDefault();

         });

         });
         jQuery.fn.selectText = function(){
             this.find('input').each(function() {
                if($(this).prev().length == 0 || !$(this).prev().hasClass('p_copy')) { 
                   $('<p class="p_copy" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1;"></p>').insertBefore($(this));
                }
            $(this).prev().html($(this).val());
        });
        var doc = document;
        var element = this[0];
            console.log(this, element);
            if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
                var range = document.body.createTextRange();
                range.moveToElementText(element);
                    range.select();
            } else if (window.getSelection) {
                var selection = window.getSelection();        
                var range = document.createRange();
                    range.selectNodeContents(element);
                    selection.removeAllRanges();
                    selection.addRange(range);
    }
};
</script>
```

If I access the template directly @ `http://localhost/gui/page.html` the javascript works, but if I access it through `http://localhost/base.html` double clicking on the field does nothing.

I've tried including the javascript in the base.html and it still doesn't load.  How does django load javascript when calling through an included template?

Comment: Have you verified that the contents of `gui/page.html` are being included when you open `base.html`? Have you done view source in your browser to make sure that the javascript is there? Based on the URLs that you are using it appears that Apache (or your other server) is statically serving the file `base.html` rather than allowing django to serve the file in which case the template is not being processed and not including `gui/page.html`. How is your web server set up?

Comment: Strange, so I took the `<script></script>` tags and put the contents into a `js/scripts.js` file and it works.

Comment: It sounds like your django application is not running. You either need to call `python manage.py runserver` from your django project directory or your mod_wsgi or gunicorn to run your django project. Are you using any of those?

Comment: wha?  Yes the application is running.  If it wasn't running I wouldn't be able to browse the site.... Anyways, it's working.  As I stated I put the scripts into a static file and it loaded from there.  Odd it wouldn't load it if I had the script in tags in the html template.

Comment: How did you start the Django application running?

Comment: python manage.py runserver dviappserver01:80

Comment: You can't load extra js from included templates. You have to either add it to some `block`s or just import it to the template. I think you icnluded it to `base.html` wrong. Can you show how you did that?

Comment: @whoisearth: Did you manage to get it worked, I have the same issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just had the same issue. In order to solve it, it is necessary to do the next thing:

1. In base.html add:

   - all basic scripts, such us

   `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>`

   - add block, something like:

   `{% block extrascripts %}{% endblock %}`
2. Put your hand-made script to `/static/js/hand_made.js`
3. In the `child` template, which are included, i.e that one which we use in `{% include 'child_template.html' %}` :

   - at the top add `{% load staticfiles %}`
   - at the middle add your html
   - at the end add

   `{% block extrascripts %}<script type="text/JavaScript" src="{%  static 'js/hand_made.js' %}"></script>{% endblock %}` (can not add it with a nice style for some reason).

If for some reasons you need to provide data from template to JS, you need to do the next:

```
{% block extrascripts %}
    <script>
        var my_var_1 = "{{ some_template_data.var_1 }}",
            my_var_2 = "{{ some_template_data.var_12 }}";
    </script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="{%  static 'js/hand_made.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

In this case `my_var_1` and `my_var_2` will be available in `hand_made.js`

Answer (score 1):

Django does not modify or load any javascript in a template. It will simply pass it through to the output.

Comment: apologies I actually did have quotes around the include on the HTML so I updated to show that.  My understanding is the javascript I have in page.html should work even when on an include tag but it doesn't.  How do I get it to?

Answer (score 0):

I came across same issue. I was not able to find any best solution with minimal change, so commenting here my perspective/solution to resolve this issue.

step1: Include alpine.js to your project.

step2: Include js function:

1. JS function in  in root of the include template (base.html or any extends template where you are including the include template).
2. or include JS file in any of the template file.

step3: In include template add x-init="your JS function" (from alpinejs) to the element. `<div x-init="jsfunction"></div>`

above is going to resolves the issue.